# Use NLog in Multithreading application skip the log messages

Tags: nlog, transaction-log

I am using NLog for my simple C#.Net application it works fine.
but when i use **NLog for C#.Net multithreading** application it **skips the log messages**

I also tried to configure NLog.config using AsyncWrapper and AutoFlushWrapper
but it does not work properly still some messages skipped.

So,Please Any Body tell me  what is the best way to Configure NLog for Multithreading application without skipping any Log Messages?

Comment: Could you post the config file?

Comment: Did you tried to turn on internal NLog logging? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging